# ConcurrentHashMap<String,PriorityBockingQueue> traversal with threads facing Error : Cannot refer to the non-final local variable

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having a HashMap whose value for each key is PriorityBlockingQueue and I need to poll each Key's priority queue in separate thread. My MapTraversal function looks like below.  But compiler insist on making PriorityBlockingQueue object as final as its being polled inside thread. But how can I assign value for each key to PriorityBlockingQueue ops if I make it final. Please help me clarify my understanding.

```
private void mapExecution(){
            for(String s:hMap.keySet()){
                PriorityBlockingQueue<Obj> ops = hMap.get(s);
                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                 // Java insists on making ops as final but I need to assign to ops value of each key 
                        while(hMap.get(ops).size() != 0){
                            Obj o = ops.poll();
                         //Do something with o

                        }
                    }
                });
                t.start();
            }
    }
```

Comment: Why can't you make ops final? After making ops final it compiles.

Comment: If you really need outscoped non-final value, so create a non-anonymous runnable with constructor parameter. You question is like, why water is blue and grass is green. That's a java restriction, that you can operate with outscoped local value only if it is final or effectively final.

Comment: "but I need to assign to ops value of each key" - that's not a problem. You can still make ops final because you declared it inside the for-loop. So for each key there will be a "different" final ops.